# Strip HTML from string in SSRS 2005 (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

my **SSRS DataSet** returns a field with HTML, e.g.

```
<b>blah blah </b><i> blah </i>.
```

how do i strip all the HTML tags? has to be done with **inline** VB.NET

Changing the data in the table is not an option.

**Solution found** ... = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(StringWithHTMLtoStrip, "<[^>]+>","")

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanx to Daniel, but I needed it to be done inline ... here's the solution:

`= System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(StringWithHTMLtoStrip, "<[^>]+>","")`

Here are the links:

http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2003/05/13/6963.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Here's a good example using Regular Expressions: https://web.archive.org/web/20210619174622/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/042501-1.shtml

Answer (score 1):

If you know the HTML is well-formed enough, you could, if you make sure it has a root node, convert the data in that field into a System.Xml.XmlDocument and then get the InnerText value from it.

Again, you will have to make sure the text has a root node, which you can add yourself if needs be, since it will not matter, and make sure the HTML is well formed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use regular expressions (for example if you need better performance) you could try [a small method I wrote a while ago, posted at CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MCMS/htmlTagStripper.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I would go to Report Properties and then code and add the following

```
Dim mRemoveTagRegex AS NEW System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<(.|\n)+?>", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Compiled)

Function RemoveHtml(ByVal text As string) AS string
  If text IsNot Nothing Then
    Return mRemoveTagRegex.Replace(text, "")
  End If 
End Function
```

Then you can use `Code.RemoveHtml(Fields!Content.Value)` to remove the html tags.

In my opinion this is preferable then having multiple copies of the regex.