# Tab character in SSRS Expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a requirement in SSRS report, wherein I need to write an expression which replaces a string having Chr(9) with a tab character. The data is fetched from stored procedure and it has tab characters [Chr(9)] which needs to be replaced with a tab in SSRS. I have tried various solutions(like adding spaces, vbTab, etc.) from different forums, but none seem to work.

For a newline, we use a vb constant ‘vbcrlf’. Similarly I am looking something for tab. Can someone please help?

Comment: show your sample data and the expression you tried.

Comment: How your report will be rendered? HTML reduces multiple whitespaces and tabs to one single whitespace. If your report will be rendered in HTML use `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`. Try using `CHR(160) & chr(160) & chr(160) & chr(160)` for plain text formats, for PDF and Excel you have to look for the right characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get a tab to display in a rendered report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048949/can-i-get-a-tab-to-display-in-a-rendered-report)